# Fastest way to read file as a byte array

Tags: java, android

What is the fastest way to read a file as a byte array (on Android)? The file is about 4 MB. It's inside the assets directory, which means that it's probably compressed.

Currently, I'm doing something like this:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024 * 1024];
context.getAssets().open(FILE_NAME).read(buffer);
```

On Android, creating the array takes about 40 ms, reading the file about 120 ms. I suspect that the 40 ms consist mostly of filling the array with zeroes. Can I avoid this?

The file is basically a list of about 100,000 items which need to be searched through quickly.

Comment: How are you measuring the time? Note that you should be taking note of the return value of `read`.

Comment: Thanks, I assumed that it always reads as much as possible. I use a simple Measure class that calls System.nanoTime().

Comment: Have you tried using Traceview instead of `nanoTime()`?

Comment: @CommonsWare according to Traceview, the array initialization actually takes only 10 ms, the rest is GC. Another interesting thing - every method longer than couple of ms have a strange empty space in the middle (http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6875183/traceview.png) - any idea what does that mean?

Comment: Gaps in the color bars means that time was taken up by another bar elsewhere in the list of bars, meaning some other thread on a single-core environment (e.g., emulator). If those are the only four bars that are showing for you... I don't know what that means off the top of my head. I usually focus on the detail tree. To be honest, ~160ms once when your app first runs doesn't seem like a huge problem.

Comment: These are the only bars... I'm actually quite happy happy with the 150 ms (plus another 150 ms of processing the buffer), this is roughly what I was trying to achieve, I asked mostly because the 40 ms array initialiazation was puzzling...

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid creating the byte array by using the [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) class, with its [read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#read%28byte%5B%5D%29) method. The android [page](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) isn't too different, but could also be useful. I used RAF for a project to store and retrieve data whenever desired from a specific file. RAF is very useful for these tasks. However, the more you read and write, of course increases the run-time considerably. Here is an example of its usage:

```
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class RAFTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RandomAccessFile raf;
        String metadata = "This is a test file.";

        try {

            raf = new RandomAccessFile(args[0], "rw");
            raf.writeUTF(metadata);
            int[] nums = new int[10];
            for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
                nums[i] = i;
                raf.writeInt(nums[i].getValue());
            }

            raf.seek(0); // force pointer to beginning

            System.out.println(raf.readUTF());
            int[] c = new int[5];
            int byteJump = 4;
            for(int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
                raf.seek(raf.getFilePointer() + byteJump);
                c[i] = raf.readInt();
                System.out.println(c[i]);
            }

        } catch(Exception ex) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I can't use it because I need to filter the items in the file really quickly (preferably below 10 ms), every time the users presses a key on the keyboard. Currently I do it in one micro-optimized loop (eg. no method calls). Any IO is out of the question :)